# Loop and Add Data to a Hashtable

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am working with a software list, and the Import-Excel module ([Link](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)), trying to create a hash table of software name and version number, with each host exported as its own sheet.  I'm using the Export-MultipleExcelSheets cmdlet within the module.

Here is a sample of what my $Inventory variable looks like:

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  103 10.105.122.27             {@{Host=10.105.122.27; Name=Update Rollup 10 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3 (KB3049853); Version=1}, @{Host=10.105.122.27; Name=Update Rollup 14 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3 (K...
  103 10.105.122.28             {@{Host=10.105.122.28; Name=Update Rollup 10 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3 (KB3049853); Version=1}, @{Host=10.105.122.28; Name=Update Rollup 14 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3 (K...
  119 10.105.76.221             {@{Host=10.105.76.221; Name=Update Rollup 10 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3 (KB3049853); Version=1}, @{Host=10.105.76.221; Name=Update Rollup 15 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3 (K...
  116 10.105.76.222             {@{Host=10.105.76.222; Name=Update Rollup 15 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3 (KB3184728); Version=1}, @{Host=10.105.76.222; Name=Update Rollup 16 for Exchange Server 2010 Service Pack 3 (K...
```

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
    Foreach ($I In $Inventory)
    {
        $DataToGather.Add($I.Name, {$I.Group | Select-Object Name, Version})
    }

    Export-MultipleExcelSheets -Show -Autosize -Path "C:\Path\To\Software Inventory.xlsx" $DataToGather
```

I get no errors with this code but it results in 10 sheets with the same software list (I know these machines do not have the same exact software list).

Is there a better way do to what I'm doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ScriptBlock { }` might be causing the behaviour that you're seeing, you should change the `ScriptBlock { }` inside the `Add` method to `Parenthesis ( )` instead.

```
Foreach ($I In $Inventory)
{
    # Change the $i.Group section to be surrounded by Parenthesis
    $DataToGather.Add($I.Name, ($I.Group | Select-Object Name, Version))
}
```

If that doesn't work try commenting out the `Export-MultupleExcelSheets` function and simply returning your `$DataToGather` variable to see what comes out, this might help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: Indeed that is the issue - once I removed it I was able to get what I was expecting back.  Now I have a different error with the Export-MultipleExcelSheets cmdlet but that's a different issue for another day.